# How to get stacktrace on error in jasmine-node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine, jasmine-node

I'm running jasmine-node using:

```
node_modules/jasmine-node/bin/jasmine-node --verbose --junitreport --noColor spec
```

but got error:

```
Exception loading: /home/kuba/projects/jcubic/terminal/repo/spec/terminalSpec.js
[TypeError: Cannot read property 'extend' of undefined]
```

Why it don't show stack trace? I'm including jsdom and jquery with the code:

```
if (typeof window === 'undefined') {
    var jsdom = require("jsdom").jsdom;
    global.window = jsdom().parentWindow;
    global.jQuery = global.$ = require("jquery")(window);
    require('../js/jquery.terminal-src');
}
```

Anybody have a clue why I got this error, the terminalSpec.js file is on [github](https://github.com/jcubic/jquery.terminal/blob/devel/spec/terminalSpec.js).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the option by checking the source code:

```
--captureExceptions
```